# Is there an upper limit on the radius of a rotating wheel?

Tags: special-relativity, rotational-dynamics, speed

Is there an upper limit on the radius of a real wheel which is rotating at an Angular frequency of $\,\omega \,$ along its axis, such that we just require a finite amount of energy to rotate it? Why/why not?

e.g. if a wheel which is rotating at an angular speed of $\omega  = 3 \times {10^5}\,{{rad} \over {\sec }}$ could have a radius of $r = 2 \times {10^3}\,meters$??

Comment: This question seems to assume an underlying inertial system by which geometric relations such as "_radius_ $r$", "_angular frequency_ $\omega$", "wheel circumfence" etc. are defined and evaluated in the first place. The speed of any element of the wheel rim travelling between members of this inertíal system is of course limited (already purely kinematically) by the speed of any signal between them: $|\omega\cdot r| \lt c_{\, 0}$. (Importantly, the question requires the wheel elements to be _real_ and not, say, just some laser pointer dot; because there's no corresponding limit on phase speed.)

Comment: @user12262: Yes, the underlying frame to define those relations is any frame which is not accelerated with respect to the point at which center of the wheel is located. Of course required energy could not be infinite but I may have to modify my question, I want to see if the upper limits (upper bound for the speed of light and therefore the limitation on radius of the wheel) of these frames is different??

Comment: Frames of reference are completely irrelevant here. If there is a point on the wheel that is moving at $c$ in some frame of reference, then it's moving at $c$ in all frames of reference. Since SR doesn't allow material objects to move at $c$, this is impossible.

Comment: @2physics: Your question, especially after the recent edit, seems to be focussed on how to define/measure "speed" (i.e. values $|\beta|$) in the first place, and to clarify the (possible) role which inertial systems may have in this definition. (This may have been conclusively addressed already somewhere; but it surely seems worth to ask the question explicitly.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is. The numbers you gave would result in the outer rim of the wheel moving at twice the speed of light. That's just not possible.

Comment: you think so? but it's not an inertial frame... Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Inertial frames got nothing to do with it. There cannot be _any_ object moving faster than light in _any_ reference frame, inertial or otherwise. This is one of the key points of special relativity. I can't give you a better explanation why, it's basically a postulate. But I'm 100% positive that it's not possible. Just as Schlomo Steinbergerstein suggested, the wheel would probably break apart while accelerating. Otherwise you would need to put in tremendous amounts of energy as the rim approaches the speed of light.

Comment: But Special relativity just talks about inertial frames of reference.. and this frame has a rotational motion , so shouldn't we expect things in it not to work according known physical laws of our inertial frame?

Comment: @2physics: It's not true that SR can only deal with inertial frames of reference. That's the way Einstein posed the distinction between the two theories a century ago, but it turns out that it's simply not true. SR deals with accelerated frames just fine. And in any case, you can consider a noninertially moving object in an inertial frame; we do it all the time in Newtonian mechanics.

Comment: @bencrowell: You said those numbers would result at twice the speed of light. But the speed of light in such rotating accelerated frames at the presence of gravitational fields is not necessarily equal to 3*10^8 m/s , is it?

Comment: @ben-crowell: In addition I saw this on wikipedia :"In non-inertial frames of reference (gravitationally curved space or accelerated reference frames), the local speed of light is constant and equal to c, but the speed of light along a trajectory of finite length can differ from c, depending on how distances and times are defined."

Comment: @ben-crowell: I've edited my question , please have a look at it.

Comment: @2physics: The WP quote is referring to a coordinate velocity. Coordinate velocities are of no fundamental interest in relativity. They're not observable. What is observable is the velocity of a particle in a local inertial frame (LIF). In any LIF, $c$ is the same.

Comment: @ben-crowell: By "Coordinate velocity" If you mean the velocity at which the coordinate system moves?? Whether they are of fundamental interest or not, their velocity is supposed to differ from c.

Comment: @2physics: Coordinate velocity means the rate at which a coordinate of a particle changes. Coordinate velocities can be less than, equal to, or greater than $c$. There is no physical constraint on them because they have no physical significance independent of the coordinate system.

Comment: @ben-crowell: I'm confused.. Is "the rate at which a coordinate of a particle changes" equal to the velocity at which the reference frame of that particle moves?? Lorentz transformation put some constraints on the velocity of all particles and frames '${x_2} = {{{x_1} - {v_1}{t_1}} \over {\sqrt {1 - {{({v \over c})}^2}} }}$' (V is the velocity of the particle or any moving frame )

Comment: @2physics: Relativity allows any smooth, one-to-one change of coordinates. One example of such a change of coordinates would be in Minkowski space if we change from standard Minkowski coordinates to a rotating frame. But any such change of coordinates is possible, e.g., I can do $x\rightarrow x+k\sin(cx)$, where $|k|<1$ so that the function is one-to-one. After an arbitrary change of coordinates, clearly derivatives of coordinates don't have any special significance. The only coordinates in which $|v|<c$ is required are coordinates that represent a (local or global) inertial frame.

Comment: Couldn't the center of tthe wheel rotate slower than the rim?

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna go along with the "may have been caused by a misunderstanding" and tell you about something else that will help clarify it.

Consider an arbitrarily long spoon. You can hold and flick it at such angular velocity that its endpoint, it may seem to you, will certainly exceed the speed of light.

But in reality, **there is no spoon**. There are atoms, perhaps silver, making up that spoon and they interact at finite speeds, therefore it takes time for the flick to traverse the entire length of the spoon.

A rotating wheel may be a different object, but the argument is basically the same.

Comment: Thanks;You mean it's impossible to rotate this wheel at such a speed??

Comment: You're welcome! :)

My point was that many paradoxes of such kind are resolved simply by considering real objects, made up of matter, not mathematically idealized rigid structures.

I don't have a precise answer, but by thinking about atoms, I'm sure that either you would create disturbances in the matter travelling at finite speeds (waves) or it would simply break apart at some point for any physical material.

Comment: Yup you are right , physical instances could be really helpful. Your spoon example was a good idea and I got it. But my question is about the probable difference between an inertial and non-inertial frame. If it doesn't make difference to be in an inertial or non-inertial frame, so why does Einstein's second principle of special relativity emphasize on constancy of light speed in all "inertial frames" not all frames??

Comment: :I've edited my question , please have a look at it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not exactly sure what you mean, I just wanted to point out these things that I pointed out!

Answer (score 0):

One of the results of special relativity as a result of (1) light cones and (2) the speed limit on the speed of light is that there is no such thing as a "rigid body" in special relativity. The reason is that a "rigid body" is one where the displacement vector between any two points is a constant. But because you have a spinning wheel, they have different velocities and the proper distance changes with the velocity.

see here: http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/rigid_disk.html for more discussion on this.

Answer (score -1):

Rotating an object faster than the speed of light just isn't possible. First of all, it would have to accelerate to that speed, and the atoms in an object cannot interact with each other faster than the speed of sound(The speed the vibrations and force can travel through the object), so it would take an awfully long time to get moving. Once the wheel even started to approach the speed of sound, nuclear fusion would occur, destroying everything. Even if none of this happened, the speed of the wheel would be capped, just under the speed of light. It couldn't even get near the speed you had in mind, Unfortunately... :(

Comment: *Once the wheel even started to approach the speed of sound, nuclear fusion would occur, destroying everything.* This is wrong.

Comment: @BenCrowell Oops, meant speed of light

Comment: It's still wrong if you replace speed of sound with speed of light.